# Cucumber-rails required outside of env.rb. The rest of loading is being defered until env.rb is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

What does this **env.rb error** mean, pls?

```
root# rake db:migrate
WARNING: Cucumber-rails required outside of env.rb.  The rest of loading is being defered until env.rb is called.
  To avoid this warning, move 'gem cucumber-rails' under only group :test in your Gemfile
```

The gemfile is here:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# for Heroku deployment - as described in Ap. A of ELLS book
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails-training-wheels'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
end
group :production do
#  gem 'pg'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer'              
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
gem 'haml'
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

that's just how bundler works, you need to add `:require => false` after `gem 'cucumber-rails'`. I have to say the error message is a bit misleading.

Comment: Actually, it's not misleading. It suggests that you create an isolated `:test` group with test gems, which is cleaner than adding `:require => false` on them, IMO.

Comment: I've found in my apps even having it inside a specific test group still produces this error, and the `:require => false` is the only way to make the error it disappear. YMMV

Comment: I had to also comment out 'guard-compass' to make it work in guard environment. Development worked fine with the re-organization of groups.

Answer (score 4):

It is suggesting that you isolate your test gems on a `:test` group. Your Gemfile will then look somewhat like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails-training-wheels'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

Personally, I liked the gem's suggestion. We really don't need the test gems loaded on our development environment.

Comment: This didn't get rid of the warning for me, but :require => false after gem 'cucumber-rails' fixed the problem.

Comment: Like travis-146, this didn't work for me either, but :require => false did.